# How to send push notification via postman using AWS Pinpoint

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, react-native, push-notification, aws-pinpoint

I want to send push notifications to mobile apps using `REST API` provided by `AWS`. I read their documentation but i am getting an error unauthorized. Does any one  able to send push notification using `REST API` ?

> The following is an example of a REST request int the documentation

```
GET /v1/apps/a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3n4o5p6/campaigns
Accept: application/json
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20161127/us- 
   east-1/mobiletargeting/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-date, 
   Signature=a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3n4o5p6q7r8s9t0u1v2w3x4y5z6a1b2c3d4e5f6
Host: pinpoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
X-Amz-Date: 20161127T202324Z
```

> Following is the error I am getting

***The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details***

Answer (score 1):

Currently, if I specify my AWS **AccessKey** & **SecretKey** in the Postman Environment as per the [Amazon Pinpoint tutorial with POSTMAN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/tutorials-using-postman-configuration.html) I also get the same error message : ***The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details*..**

To get this setup working, I have specified my AWS **AccessKey** & **SecretKey** in Postman **Authorization** tab as illustrated below :

[image]

Below is a screenshot of the push notification message received on my Android phone:

[image]